How much a general a theory of matrices equivalence under group actions we have?
Let $F$ be a field and let $M_{m,n}\,(F)$ be the $F$-linear space of $m \times n$ matrices over $F$. Let $G$ be a group acting on $M_{m,n}\,(F)$.
My question is: Do we have some theory about the orbits of the action of $G$ on $M_{m,n}\,(F)$ ? Especially, I am interested in invariants and canonical representatives for the orbits.
For sure, an entirely general theory seems out of reach, but the fact that several special cases have been studied and completely understood makes me think that some researcher might had tried to develop a general theory. Also, it seems something close to linear representation theory.
Here some of the special cases:

$G = \operatorname{GL}_m(F) \times \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ acting as $(P,Q)\star  A := P^{-1}AQ$ for each $(P, Q) \in G$ and $A \in M_{m,n}\,(F)$. The orbits are consists of the matrices of the same rank (matrix equivalence) and we can fix a canonical representative for each orbit.

For $m=n$. We have $G = \operatorname{GL}_m(F)$ acting as $P \star A := P^{-1}AP$ for each $P \in G$ and $A \in M_{m,n}\,(F)$. The orbits are consists of the matrices representing the same linear map under two (possibly) different bases (matrix similarity).

For $m=n$. We have $G = \operatorname{GL}_m(F)$ acting as $P \star A := P^{T}AP$ for each $P \in G$ and $A \in M_{m,n}\,(F)$. The orbits are consists of the matrices representing the same bilinear form with respect to (possibly) different bases (matrix congruence).

$G = \operatorname{GL}_m(F)$ acting as $P \star A := PA$ for each $P \in G$ and $A \in M_{m,n}\,(F)$. The orbits are consists of the matrices that are equivalent by row operations (matrix row equivalence). Similarly, multiplying on the right we get matrix column equivalence.


Thanks for any possible suggestion/reference.

What structure on $M_{m,n}(F)$ do you want $G$ to preserve? Is it more than just the structure as an $mn$ dimensional vector space?

In all cases you mention, linear algebra gives canonical orbit representatives, so what are you hoping for in general?

@DaveBenson I'm not sure of what do you mean.

@GeoffRobinson For example, take any of 1-4 but replace $\operatorname{GL}_m$ (resp. $\operatorname{GL_n}$) with some notable subgroup, such as $\operatorname{SL}_m$. Such a theory should quickly provide an answer for the orbits.

To elaborate on @DaveBenson's comment, $M_{m,n}(F)$ is an affine variety over the field $F$ (e.g., for simplicity assuming $F$ algebraically closed) and in your examples the groups are algebraic, and you may want the space of orbits to be a geometric object?
